# Error in the array declaration in the script file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a rails application in which I am added coffeescript code to add the functionality of the drag and drop. I didn't use coffeescript before. This is the code

```
 ready = undefined
 set_positions = undefined

 set_positions = ->
 $('.position').each (i) ->
  $(this).attr 'data-pos', i + 1

ready = ->
 set_positions()
 $('.sortable').sortable()
 $('.sortable').sortable().bind 'sortupdate', (e, ui) ->
    updated_order = []
   set_positions()
   $('.position').each (i) ->
     updated_order.push
       id: $(this).data('id')
       position: i + 1
 $.ajax
   type: 'PUT'
   url: '/portfolios/sort'
   data: {order: updated_order}

  $ ->
    ready()
```

It gives me error in the console when I try to refresh the page. `updated order is not defined`. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error probably occurs here

```
$.ajax
   type: 'PUT'
   url: '/portfolios/sort'
   data: {order: updated_order}
```

because `updated_order` is not defined in this scope. To put `updated_order` in scope, you could do

```
ready = ->
  set_positions()
  updated_order = []
  ...
```